# Cannot run asp.net mvc 2 on a subdomain while I can run on a domain

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have created an asp.net mvc 2 from template in a subdirectory of a domain. In IIS I converted it to application.

When I try to access throuh mydomain/subdomain I get

> 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied

Comment: What IIS version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

If this is IIS6, do remember to set the Wild Card Mapping for the Virtual Directory.